# Persisting the model binded object using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, model-binding

I'll try to keep this short and concise.

I got my controller here...

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(CustomObject myCustomObject)
{
     ...
}
```

Where myCustomObject looks great.  But, if I want to save this using the entity framework, I need to do something like this...

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(CustomObject myCustomObject)
{
     CustomObject existingObject = repository.GetCustomObject(myCustomObject.ID);

     // Set all the attributes of myCustomObject to existingObject
     existingObject.SomeMapperFunction(myCustomObject)

     repository.Save();
}
```

Is there a way I can keep from doing this mapping excersise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
     CustomObject existingObject = repository.GetCustomObject(id);

     TryUpdateModel(existingObject);
     // You additionaly can check the ModelState.IsValid here

     repository.Save();
}
```